# If I dismantle an exotic with a catalyst do I lose my progress?

Tags: destiny-2

I am working through a few exotic weapon catalyst quests at the moment, but I'm finding that I have quickly outleveled the weapons.

If I dismantle the item and get a new one from my Collections, will I lose my catalyst progress?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, your exotic weapons will not lose the catalyst progression if you dismantle it. Myself and [users on reddit](https://amp.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/8o8byr/if_i_dismantle_an_exotic_do_i_lose_the_catalyst/) have confirmed this.

To test, I used an exotic weapon that had a 3% catalyst progression as my guinea pig. I dismantled the exotic weapon and immediately acquired it through the collections menu. When I had viewed the weapons perks, the catalyst progression remained

The same is also true for exotic weapons with a completed catalyst and upgraded to masterwork. However, dismantling a masterwork exotic and then collecting it through the collections menu will reset the enemies defeated counter to zero.

Comment: I presume the same is true if you complete the catalyst? Checking out from collections will get you a masterwork exotic?

Comment: @DavidYell I unfortunately do not have an exotic with a completed catalyst, so I wasn't able to test that. However, if a partially completed catalyst is retained, I don't see why fully completed catalyst wouldn't. I can test that when I complete the catalsyt I'm currently working on

Comment: @DavidYell see my updates regarding masterwork weapons